# What does the phrase "A blank is a blank is a blank" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I've heard this phrase a couple times, one of them being

> A number is a number is a number.

Despite some searching, I'm still unsure what this phrase means.

Comment: Probably the best known example of this is "a rose is a rose is..." from a Gertrude Stein poem. You'll find plenty of analysis if you google that instead of "a number is..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The construction may be understood as an emphasis, a defining emphasis, an emphasis that stops further discussion of "blank".

"*A number is a number*" is a truism that could be interpreted to mean that a number is a number (agreed as an obvious superfluous statement, **but** there may be possible nuances and differences that depend on circumstance or interpretation).

For example "*A number is a number*" is unquestionably true, but most mathematicians immediately think "*Yes, but what sort of number? real, integer, rational, irrational, imaginary* ... and so forth).

To say "*a number is a number is a number*" is to say that there is no need or purpose in considering any of these questions. A number is a number, and that is the end of the matter; think no further; any more speculation or qualification, as to what sort of number or any other issues, is not required or wanted.

Comment: I hazard a guess that the downvoter is not a mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

"An X is an X is an X" -> (i) All [the] Xs are the same; (ii) in this example: "There is nothing special about the number that you are referring to, or any other number."